# How do I move objects between sandboxes?

Tags: deployment, custom-object, eclipse

I want to move a bunch of objects from one sandbox to another and so far it's been a pretty large nightmare.  I select an object in Eclipse, select Deploy To Server and wait for an error to appear telling me the dependent pieces that also need to be moved.  Rinse and repeat for the next object.

Is there a tool that figures out dependencies and moves them in a more efficient manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Change Set to move objects between sandboxes, assuming that the two sandboxes are authorized to exchange Change Sets with each other. You could also use the Eclipse IDE or Migration Toolkit, although these are relatively more complicated than a change set.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you very much - a huge time saver.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the metadata (including all dependencies) exist in the target instance, I would consider moving things over using an unmanaged package. Adding to a package will automatically pull in all dependent metadata. However, you cannot install an unmanaged package with a particular metadata component (like a custom field) that exists in the target sandbox.

Comment: Packaging is a good option yes, however there are some metadata items that cannot be packaged, and thus changesets is the best way to move these 'un-packageable' items from Sandbox to production.